# Clarification on two weapon fighting and barbarian multiple attacks

Tags: dnd-5e

I have a 5th level barbarian who gets two attacks, as part of his class abilities. If I choose to employ the standard two-weapon fighting style using two hand-axes, my attack sequence looks like this in a round:

1st attack: Attack with primary hand 2nd attack: Attack with primary hand

Bonus action: Attack with secondary hand.

I can choose where to place the bonus action (after attack 1 or 2) BUT I do not get it for each action, since there can't be more than one bonus action per turn.

Essentially, this nets me 3 attacks per round and not 4. Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: Hi @SilverBlade--I believe the linked question's answer describes which of your interpretations is correct. If I've missed some difference between the two scenarios please edit your question to make the distinction clearer. And welcome to the site!